# What type of catalyst would this be?

Tags: phase, catalysis

We were discussing types of catalysts, homogeneous and heterogeneous.

Our question is: If you have two reactants, one reagent is aqueous and the other is a gas, and the catalyst is aqueous, what type of catalyst is it?

My guessing is that it is a homogeneous catalyst because the gas will dissolve in the solution at some point so that the reaction can occur. What is your guess?

Comment: There is no point in guessing. You don't know whether the reaction actually occurs in the solution or on the surface. It can turn out either way.